# Work item [WF task] not showing in UWL

Tags: abap

We had work items displayed in Work list of UWL but for the past few months the work items are not displayed.

1. The work items are appearing in SAP business workplace (inbox)
2. The agents are assigned correctly

Since I have a super admin portal access I could see all the workitems those were raised [being a part of agent aswell] but for the rest of the users they are not able to view the work items in the worklist [UWL]. Those who are not able to view the work list are having a warning shown as attached.

[Warning in UWL: User is missing credential for connecting to alias snp12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pj5C8.jpg)

Any inputs on what needs to be checked please? Also would like to know the job that updates the work items in the worklist.

The work item/workflow task is a custom one which was working earlier

Answer (score 0):

In the NWA under the admin account you should have access to [System Administration](http://www.sweetlets.com/w/uploads/2010/09/parmigration.png) tab.

Go to `System Administration` >> `System Configuration` >> `Universal Worklist and Workflow` >> `Universal Worklist Administration` and check what connectors are registered and their status. If some are deactivated try to activate them again.